# hibernate results join left

Tags: java, hibernate

I've stack over one small thing:

I have two tables in database, which are related - User and UserReference.

In *UserReference* i have field **userid**, which is related to **id** in *User*.

i have query to mysql with join left:

```
"FROM User as user left join fetch user.userReferences WHERE login='"+login+"' or email='"+login+"' AND password = '" +password+ "'" ;
```

The query is ok and i get results.

I send the results to controller, changing it into list: query.list();

In controller i receive the results and push it into **user** list.

From the **user** list i can get info from table **User**

In table **User** there is:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<UserReference> getUserReferences() {
    return this.userReferences;
}
```

And now - i want to get data from table **UserReference** which are in **user** list, becouse my query have JOIN.

How can i do it?

i was trying to do something like this:

```
List<UserReference> userReference = (List<UserReference>) user.get(0).getUserReferences();
            System.out.println(userReference.get(0).getAge());
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a Set to a List,  iterate over the Set to get userRefences instead.